# Persist key isn't removed when trying localStorage.remove() | React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage, persist, redux-persist

I've configured a persist store with my UserReducer, in order to keep the user logged in when navigating through the app & refreshing.
The key is created in my localStorage as expected, but when trying to remove it, nothing happens.

handleLogout function (the state for isLoggedIn changes to false as it should):

```
 const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("persist:main-root");
    vacationlyStore.dispatch(isLoggedIn(false));
    navigate("/login");
  };
```

persist config and store:

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: "main-root",
  storage: storage,
};

const persistedUserReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userReducer);

export const vacationlyStore = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    vacations: vacationReducer,
    users: persistedUserReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleWare) =>
    getDefaultMiddleWare({ serializableCheck: false }),
});
export const persistor = persistStore(vacationlyStore);
```

and my index.tsx has the provider and persistGate:

```
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={vacationlyStore}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <MainLayout />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

I've tried persist.purge() and .flush() but no success with those as well.
Also, when I run localStorage.removeItem("persist:main-root") in the console itself, it removes it. I thought it may have something to do with CORS but I've enabled CORS in my server.ts file..

any ideas for solution?

Thanks in advance!